# I need info on how to use the find_overlap function

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I  am coding a program and I am trying to use the find_overlap with a functions coordinates. here is the code

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

coords = 1082, 473
canvas = Canvas(root, width=1080, height=960)
frame = Frame(root, width=209, height=960)


def cords(event):
    print(event.x, event.y)



def click(event):
   canvas_id = canvas.create_line(event.x, event.y, coords)
   canvas.after(100,canvas.delete,canvas_id)



line = click

canvas.bind('<Button-1>',line)

obj1=canvas.create_line(247,157,605,482)
obj2=canvas.create_line(802,720,270,640)

canvas.find_overlapping(247,157,)

photo = PhotoImage(file='76.gif')
label = Label(frame, image=photo)
label.config(image=photo)
label.pack()

frame.pack(side='right')
canvas.pack(side='left')
root.mainloop()
```

I just need to know how to use find_overlap function with the click function.

Comment: What part about it don't you understand? You give it the coordinates of a rectangle and it finds anything that overlaps.

Comment: i am trying to get it to use the function click with the other lines also how would you use the function in an if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You give it the coordinates of a rectangle and it finds anything that overlaps